# Does GMSMapView:clear dealloc all GMSMarker objects?

Tags: ios, google-maps, gmsmapview

Does the method `[GMSMapView clear]` dealloc the `GMSMarker` objects as well or are they still kept in memory.

I reckon that the method only sets the property `map` to nil and the object is still in the memory. Does anyone knows about that?

[Class reference of GMSMarker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface%5fg%5fm%5fs%5fmarker)

Comment: hey you got any solution for this I am facing same issue.